# GraphQL Client with React frontend subscription not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I started to add a websocket to my React app and I managed to handle the back-end part with nodejs just fine, working perfectly with GraphQL playground.  However, I can't get my subscriptions to work from the client side.

I did everything the documentation told me to, set up my websocket and my websocket connect without any trouble.

```
 const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: ws://myUrl,
    options: {
       connectionParams
     }
  );

function splitByOperation({ query }) {
  const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
  return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
}
let link = ApolloLink.from([
  authLink,
  errorLink,
  uploadLink,
  stateLink,
  ApolloLink.split(
    // split based on operation type
    splitByOperation,
    wsLink,
    httpLink
  )
]);


  const Client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: '/graphql',
    cache,
    resolvers,
    link
  });
```

which result in :

```
 Request URL: ws://myUrl:3000/subscription
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols
```

in my console.
My main problem is : when using "useSubscription" like that :

```
const COMMENTS_SUBSCRIPTION = gql`
  subscription OnCommentAdded {
    commentAdded {
      id
      content
    }
  }
`;

 const { data: { commentAdded }, loading } = useSubscription(
   COMMENTS_SUBSCRIPTION
 );
```

My data `commentAdded` is always null, I strongly suspect the `useSubscription` hook doesn't subscribe at all since my subscription resolve in the backend act like there's no one to send the data to.

Also, in the network part of my chrome dev tools there's nothing except my first interaction with the websocket when setting up apollo client.

I have no error to work with and I'm pretty much lost at this point.

The names and field requested match perfectly, nothing wrong when using my backend playground, still in my frontend playground I get this when trying to use the subscription :

```
Could not connect to websocket endpoint ws://myUrl/subscription. Please check if the endpoint url is correct.
```

I'm using apollo-client 2.6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured this out.

```
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: 'ws://localhost:3000/subscription',
  options: {
    connectionParams
  }
});
function splitByOperation({query}) {
  const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
  return (
    definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
    definition.operation === 'subscription'
  );
}

const link = ApolloLink.from([ApolloLink.split(
  // split based on operation type
  splitByOperation,
  wsLink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink)
),
uploadLink,
stateLink,
errorLink]);

// apollo client definition
const Client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '/graphql',
  cache,
  resolvers,
  link
});
```

correct syntaxe :

```
function splitByOperation({query}) {
  const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
  return (
    definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
    definition.operation === 'subscription'
  );
}

const link = ApolloLink.from([ApolloLink.split(
  // split based on operation type
  splitByOperation,
  wsLink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink)
),
uploadLink,
stateLink,
errorLink]);

const Client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '/graphql',
  cache,
  resolvers,
  link
});
```

i was using HTTP all along.